# function of that is not of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

**Problem:**

Let $g(x)=x^{-2}sin(x^{-2})$ for $x\in [-1,1]-{0}$ and $g(0)=0$.
Show that $g$ is not of bounded variation.

**Questions regarding to these kind of problems**

There are some theorems which allow me to check if something is of bounded variation, but Im not sure how to use them to prove that a function **is not** of bounded variation, for example:

1. If $g$ is differentiable at $[a,b]$ and there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $|g'(x)|\leq M$, then $g$ is of bounded variation. Now, if I can prove that g(x) is differentiable but not bounded for some $M>0$ that means $g$ is not of bounded variation? I dont think so cause I can think of some counterexample.
2. If $g$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$ and $g\in L^{1}([a,b])$, then g is bounded variation and the total variation is given by $\int_{a}^{b} |g'(x)|dx$. The problem here is that we can come up with some functions of bounded variation which are not integrable in its domain. Right, I havent been able yet but I think its possible haha.
3. The other theorem is Jordan's theorem but Im not even gonna try to use it in here.

Now, how can I prove that something is not of bounded variation then? D:

Thanks so much for your help, have a great week :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function of bounded varaition is bounded.  Consider the points  $x_n=\frac 1 {\sqrt {(4n+1)/2}}$. Note that $|g(x_n)|=\frac {(4n+1)\pi} 2$. It follows that $g$ is not bounded, hence not of bounded variation.